# Nbextensions not installing properly

Tags: python

I am having troublings enabling nbextensions. I successfully installed it by typing

```
pip install jupyter_contrib_nbextensions
```

I then relaunched anaconda and ran in my notebook:

```
jupyter contrib nbextension install --user
```

However, it threw me an error:

```
File "<ipython-input-1-1c0e089b301b>", line 1
    jupyter contrib nbextension install --user
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can anyone please help me with enabling nbextensions on my notebook? Thanks in advance! Much appreciated!!

Comment: Have you enabled the extension?

Comment: @ewong no, I can't install the javascript and css file which is required before enabling the extension. I am following this guide: https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#install-the-python-package

Answer (score 0):

Try adding hyphen in your command, also I think that `nbextension` should be in plural